# Get data attribute inside multiple children

Tags: performance, jquery

I have this issue: **Multiple classes with several span inside of each class and want to extract all data attributes of the first class.**

```
<div class="parent_class">
 <span data-year="a_1">Data</span>
 <span data-make="b_1">Data</span>
 <span data-model="c_1">Data</span>
 <span data-motor="d_1">Data</span>
</div>

<div class="parent_class">
  <span data-year="a_2">Data 2</span>
  <span data-make="b_2">Data 2</span>
  <span data-model="c_2">Data 2</span>
  <span data-motor="d_2">Data 2</span>
</div>
```

I have made several tries and just got the first data attribute with not problem.

```
var year_response = $('.parent_class:first span').data('year');

   Response:
   year_response = a1;
```

But when I tried for the make and other data attribute I got undefined

```
Actual:
var make_response = $('.parent_class:first span').data('make');

**Response: 
make_response = undefined;**

Desire:
var make_response = $('.parent_class:first span').data('make');

**Response: 
make_response = b_1;**
```

Comment: i didnt think that jquery stored data like that for a given element.  I thought it associated a key with an element which is used to store the data in lists behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just fetching all data attributes of the spans as objects and mapping them to an array :

```
var data = $.map($('.parent_class:first span'), function(el) {
    return $(el).data();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ns7RQ/)

or an object if all the data attributes are different :

```
var data = {};

$.each($('.parent_class:first span'), function(i, el) {
    $.each($(el).data(), function(k,v) {data[k] = v});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ns7RQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo!...second solution was the perfect solution for me!!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to get the first span, but the you want the second span (the one with make). What about getting the first with the make data attribute?

```
console.log($('.parent_class > span[data-make]:first').data('make'));
```

You could also select the nth element with the nth-child selector:

```
console.log($('.parent_class > span:nth-child(2)').data('make'));
```